# Why does my jQuery page lose composure after going inactive for a while

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've noticed that after a short period of time when I come back to the page with jQuery on it, specifically, when I use `.tabs()` with ajax, the inner page content doesn't have any libraries loaded into it, but the page controlling the tabs does, so the inner ajax page piggybacks on the controller pages libraries, like jQuery and UI.  But when I come back to the page after a period of time, the inner page loses composure meaning, functions can't be found, they don't work right or don't even work at all.  This also happens when i use datatables.  I tried googling but found nothing, anyone else experience this type of behavior from jQuery?

Is it somekind of cache issue with the browser or what

Comment: Do you have any rogue intervals running? I have experienced odd things with my js if left running for hours on certain sites, but not really consistently

Comment: setInterval() function. Something that evaluates in a constant loop, eating up memory if not handled properly. Same for recursive functions that may not be meeting a condition to cease.